# How to turn selected pages in MS word to landscape?

Tags: microsoft-word, landscape

I just want to select certain pages in a document and set them to landscape orientation.  There are alot of web pages on this topic.  None of them are of any use to me: my MS Word (2016 for Mac OSX) has neither a Page Setup Dialog Box Launcher nor a Page Setup Tab.  Can anyone tell me how to do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### I want to select certain pages in a document and set them to landscape orientation

> My MS Word (2016 for Mac OSX) has neither a Page Setup Dialog Box Launcher nor a Page Setup Tab

You can get to the Page Setup dialog from Menu Bar > Format > Document > Layout > Page Setup.

See below for detailed instructions.

---

#### Change the orientation for specific pages

> 1. Select all the text on the pages you want to change.
>
>    Tip: To change the orientation for all pages after the cursor,
>      instead of selecting text, click where you want to start the new page
>      orientation. On the Format menu, click Document, click Page Setup,
>      select the orientation you want, and then click OK. Next to Apply to,
>      click This point forward.
> 2. On the Format menu, click Document.
> 3. Click Page Setup at the bottom of the dialog box.
> 4. Next to Orientation, click the orientation you want, and then click OK.
> 5. Next to Apply to, click Selected text, and then click OK.

Source [Print a document in landscape or portrait orientation in Word 2016 for Mac](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Print-a-document-in-landscape-or-portrait-orientation-in-Word-2016-for-Mac-66596604-a3f6-4090-9243-7a34745891d9)

---

#### Change the orientation for specific pages

To set the orientation, go to the Layout tab.   Click the dropdown arrow below the Orientation button.

It looks like this:

[image]

You will be asked to select between Landscape and Portrait.

[image]

Source [Page Formatting In Word 2016](https://www.universalclass.com/articles/computers/office-365/page-formatting-in-word-2016.htm)

Comment: Thank you!  BTW, on my MS Word, there is no dropdown arrow below the Orientation button.  But your first answer works great!